# Random thumbnails Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails, random-access

I'm trying to load 4 random thumbnails at the end of each post on Wordpress and each thumbnail should link to its respective post. I can't figure out how to do it properly, since I have very little knowledge of PHP. I have found this code snippet in the theme that get the thumbnail and the title:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 tiles" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post' ); ?> itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

    <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       echo '<div class="post-thumbnail">';
       echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">';
       echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'shop_isle_blog_image_size' );
       echo '</a>';
       echo '</div>';
       }
     ?>
     <div class="tile_title">
        <a class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Furthermore, the thumbnails should come from the same category as the current post. E.g. if someone is reading a blogpost from the "Travel" category the 4 thumbnails should only come from this category, and the same goes for the rest of the categories. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: There are many wordpress plugins available to do this job. You can check this link for code. http://beginnersbook.com/2013/09/display-related-posts-thumbnails-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Thank you so much Ravinder! The "Related Posts based on Category" was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "related posts" feature. There are many plugins for this, for example [YARPP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/) is one such plugin.

If you want to avoid plugin, you can get theme that has this functionallity in the template itself. My blog for example uses [Ribbon theme](https://mythemeshop.com/themes/ribbon/) and contains this code.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I will check out YARPP and see if I can make it work :)